# Calendar in python/django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a website with weekly votations, but only the first three weeks of the month, so in each instance I have a start_date and end_date field.

I'd like to know if there's a way to automitically create these instances based on the current date, for instance:

Today it is 6 of March, and votations end tomorrow, so a function should be run (tmrw) that, taking into account this month calendar, would fill in the appropiate dates for the next votations. What calendar do you recommend me, and how shoul I do it?

(Never mind the automatically run part, I'll go with celery).

Thanks!

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
You've asked for an off-site resource and and open-ended coding instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your problem is and I don't know what votations are. But as a general direction of thinking: there is [`timeboard`](https://github.com/mmamaev/timeboard) library that can generate rule-based schedules (calendars) and do calculations over them (DISCLAIMER: I am the author).

The code below designates, for every month of 2018, the days of the first three weeks of the month as 'on-duty' (i.e. 'active', 'usable') and the rest as 'off-duty':

```
>>> import timeboard as tb
>>> weekly = tb.Organizer(marker='W', structure=[[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0]])
>>> monthly = tb.Organizer(marker='M', structure=[weekly])
>>> clnd = tb.Timeboard(base_unit_freq='D', 
...                     start='01 Jan 2018', end='31 Dec 2018', 
...                     layout=monthly)
```

For example, in March 2018, the days from Thursday, 1st, through Sunday, 18th, are marked 'on-duty', and the days 19-31 are marked 'off-duty'.

Now you can move along the calendar picking only on-duty days. For example, adding 1 to March, 17 gives you March 18:

```
>>> (clnd('17 Mar 2018') + 1).to_timestamp()
Timestamp('2018-03-18 00:00:00')
```

However, adding 2 carries you over to April 1, as March 19 is NOT within the first 3 weeks of March:

```
>>> (clnd('17 Mar 2018') + 2).to_timestamp()
Timestamp('2018-04-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you! I found that the calendar module of python is also a good choice.